# SQL Connection From powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlcmd

I'm trying to connect my script to a Database.
Previously I made it with:

```
psexec \\servername -accepteula sqlcmd.exe -U username -P password -S database -Q query
```

Now, I want to convert it into powershell code.
I'm trying this:

```
Enter-PSSession servername
$SQLCred = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential("username","password")
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Database",$SQLCred)
$Connection.Open()
```

But I always get this error:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'username'."
```

Of course I'm sure the credentials are correct.
Which could be the difference between the two modes of connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credentials are provided in the connection string:

```
$instance = "myInstance"
$userId = "myUserId"
$password = "myPassword"

$connectionString = "Data Source=$instance;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=master; User Id=$userId; Password=$password;"

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
```

If you have an existing credential object, you can use it like this:

```
$cred = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.credential($userId, $password)
$connectionString = "Data Source=$Instance;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=master; User Id = $($cred.username); Password = $($cred.GetNetworkCredential().password);"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $SQLCredential = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential($SQLUserName, $SQLPassword)
    $SQLServerConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=$SQLInstanceName; Initial Catalog=MASTER")
    $SQLServerConnection.Credential = $SQLCredential
    try
    {
        $SQLServerConnection.Open()
    }
```

Comment: I can see how this is different from the code in the question, but a short explanation *why* this code works, while the above one doesn't, would greatly benefit the uninitiated.